# Why doesn't normalizing the vectors in quiver plot work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm creating a vector field using the quiver plot and I would like to have all the vectors of unit length. Why doesn't the following work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \def\length{sqrt(1+(x-y)^2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    view={0}{90},
    domain=-2:2,
    y domain=-2:2,
    xmax=2, ymax=2,
    samples=15
]
\addplot3 [gray, quiver={u={1/(\length)}, v={(x^2+y^2-1)/(\length)}, scale arrows=0.1, every arrow/.append style={-latex}}] (x,y,0);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works for me. What is the problem? Is the output wrong?

Comment: My output shows vectors of varying length. They are not of equal length.

Comment: Could you post an image of the output and what version of pgfplots you are using?

Comment: I've updated the question showing the version of pgfplots (I've tried different versions) and included an image of my output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your equation for determining the length is wrong. You need to use `sqrt(1+(x^2+y^2-1)^2)`, since the x and y components of the unscaled arrows are `1` and `x^2+y^2-1`, respectively. Note that you should set `axis equal image` in this case, to make sure that you have the same unit vector lengths for both axes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \def\length{sqrt(1+(x^2+y^2-1)^2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    view={0}{90},
    domain=-2:2,
    y domain=-2:2,
    xmax=2, ymax=2,
    samples=15,
    axis equal image
]
\addplot3 [gray, quiver={u={1/\length}, v={(x^2+y^2-1)/\length}, scale arrows=0.2, every arrow/.append style={-latex}}] (x,y,0);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```